# Short syntax for adding variable and constant inside SQL query, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, addition

Is there any more elegant way how to write such a condition?

```
WHERE date<'".($date+1)."-07-01'
```

Something similar to

```
WHERE date<'{($date+1)}-07-01'
```

Comment: [Parameterise prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496) and this "problem" goes away!

Comment: Are you looking for the [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function?

Comment: SQL also had a `CONCAT()` function, or `ADDDATE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = 2013;
$truedate = ($date + 1) . "-07-01";

$preparedDb = new DB;
$preparedDb->prepare("SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE date < ?")
   ->execute(array($truedate));
```

Comment: Looks like this is the only way how to solve that when it repeats frequently, otherwise stick to the "" syntax

Comment: @user965748 NO do not use "" syntax